# React Error while importing Google Maps module

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have created a webpage using react that displays a real-time map using Google Maps API, an array of strings with geographical addresses is given. All those addresses are to reflect on Google Maps using a marker at their respective addresses. However, I am getting the following error:

Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `Map`.
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

```
Check the render method of `Map`.
    at createFiberFromTypeAndProps (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:47804:21)
    at createFiberFromElement (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:47825:19)
    at reconcileSingleElement (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:36916:27)
    at reconcileChildFibers (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:36966:39)
    at reconcileChildren (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:39908:32)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:40745:9)
    at beginWork (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:41973:20)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:26983:18)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:27027:20)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:27084:35)
```

My Map component code is:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { MapContainer, Marker, GoogleApiWrapper } from 'google-maps-react';
import { Loader } from '@googlemaps/js-api-loader';

const Map = ({ google }) => {
    const [addresses, setAddresses] = useState([
        '1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA',
        '1 Infinite Loop, Cupertino, CA',
        '350 Fifth Avenue, New York, NY',
    ]);

    const [coordinates, setCoordinates] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const loader = new Loader({
            apiKey: 'YOUR_API',
            version: 'weekly',
            libraries: ['places'],
        });

        loader.load().then(() => {
            const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

            const fetchCoordinates = async () => {
                const coordinates = [];

                for (let i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
                    const result = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        geocoder.geocode({ address: addresses[i] }, (result, status) => {
                            if (status === 'OK') {
                                resolve(result[0].geometry.location);
                            } else {
                                reject(status);
                            }
                        });
                    });

                    coordinates.push(result);
                }

                setCoordinates(coordinates);
            };

            fetchCoordinates();
        });
    }, [addresses, google.maps.Geocoder, google.maps.places]);

    return (
        <MapContainer google={google} center={{ lat: 37.7749, lng: -122.4194 }} zoom={10}>
            {coordinates.map((coordinate, index) => (
                <Marker key={index} position={{ lat: coordinate.lat(), lng: coordinate.lng() }} />
            ))}
        </MapContainer>
    );
};

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
    apiKey: 'YOUR_API',
})(Map);
```

My App.js code is:

```js
import { GoogleApiWrapper } from 'google-maps-react';
import Map from './components/locator/loc';

function App(props) {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Map google={props.google} />
        </div>
    );
}

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
    apiKey: 'YOUR_API',
})(App);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `MapContainer` is not exported from `google-maps-react`.
If you simply define a `MapContainer` to replace the one you try to import from the package, the code runs fine.

```js
const MapContainer = () => {
  return <p>Hello world!</p>;
};
```